# Issue with base adapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-listview, baseadapter

I am using listview in my android project. For this I have created a child of BaseAdapter. But I am getting error and app is crashing.

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    val restaurantListView:ListView? = activity?.findViewById(R.id.restaurant)
    restaurantListView?.adapter = RestaurantAdapter()
    }
}

class RestaurantAdapter:BaseAdapter()
{
override fun getCount(): Int {
return 3
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return Any()
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return 0
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
    return null
}
}
```

> 2019-01-27 19:32:50.372 25975-25975/com.example.foodtaskerkotlin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.foodtaskerkotlin, PID: 25975
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2379)
>           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
>           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>   2019-01-27 19:32:50.372 25975-25975/com.example.foodtaskerkotlin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: `getView()` cannot return `null`.

Comment: for now I am not using any data. I have created design I just want to see if it's working or not. How can I create empty view?

Comment: `getCount` returning 3 and `getView()` returning `null` ? What are you trying to do . IMHO migrate to `RecyclerView` now `ListView` is now in legacy.

Comment: I am trying to implement something like tableView in iOS

Comment: If you want an empty View, return an empty View.

Comment: return LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.restaurant_item,null) How to change this to Kotlin. getActivity() is not defined here. I got your point I have to send views from xml

Comment: If your `RestaurantAdapter` is nested in the `Fragment` class, then make it `inner class RestaurantAdapter:BaseAdapter()`, and use `this@Fragment.activity` in place of `getActivity()`. Otherwise, add a `Context` or `Activity` parameter to its constructor, and pass it in.

Comment: Thanks Brother. It worked.

Comment: Oh, yeah, ignore that edit. Just `activity` will work there. Cool. Glad you got it working. Cheers!